# GPS format in PHP

Tags: php, gps

how made in PHP from format 52.593800, 21.448850 format +52° 35' 37.68", +21° 26' 55.86" like do it google http://maps.google.pl/maps?hl=pl&t=m&q=52.593800,21.448850 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Source](http://www.web-max.ca/PHP/misc_6.php)

```
<?php

function DMStoDEC($deg,$min,$sec)
{

// Converts DMS ( Degrees / minutes / seconds ) 
// to decimal format longitude / latitude

    return $deg+((($min*60)+($sec))/3600);
}    

function DECtoDMS($dec)
{

// Converts decimal longitude / latitude to DMS
// ( Degrees / minutes / seconds ) 

// This is the piece of code which may appear to 
// be inefficient, but to avoid issues with floating
// point math we extract the integer part and the float
// part by using a string function.

    $vars = explode(".",$dec);
    $deg = $vars[0];
    $tempma = "0.".$vars[1];

    $tempma = $tempma * 3600;
    $min = floor($tempma / 60);
    $sec = $tempma - ($min*60);

    return array("deg"=>$deg,"min"=>$min,"sec"=>$sec);
}
```

Should be trivial to change the array to the desired string.

Comment: @Gordon: Do you know how to reduce the difference is caused by conversion between Degrees and DMS?

Answer (score 10):

Straight from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#Conversion_from_DMS_to_Decimal_Degree):

Given a decimal longitudinal coordinate such as -87.728055 it is trivial to convert it to DMS form. It will be necessary to know whether it is a latitudinal or longitudinal coordinate in order to fully convert it. The method is as follows:

- Subtract the whole number portion of the coordinate, leaving the fractional part. The whole number is the number of degrees. 87.728055 = 87 degrees.
- Multiply the remaining fractional part by 60. This will produce a number of minutes in the whole number portion. 0.728055 x 60 = 43.6833 = 43 minutes.
- Multiply the fractional part of the number of minutes by 60, producing a number of seconds. 0.6833 x 60 = 40.998 = 41 seconds. It is possible to count this as 40 seconds, truncating the decimal, round it to 41, or keep the entire number.
- Depending on whether the source number was a latitudinal or longitudinal coordinate, and the sign of the number, add the N/S/E/W specifier. The following table shows the possibilities:

```
  Type   Dir.   Sign    Test
  Lat.   N      +       > 0
  Lat.   S      -       < 0
  Long.  E      +       > 0
  Long.  W      -       < 0
```

A coordinate with at 0°0'0" latitude or longitude is neither North nor South, East nor West. It is simply zero latitude or zero longitude.

The final result is: W 87°43'41".

Comment: do you know how to reduce the difference is caused by conversion between Degrees and DMS? Thanks